# Datadog string encoding when character is not from English alphabet

Tags: java, datadog

I have a service and send Datadog events from it using com.github.arnabk.java-dogstatsd-client. In order to send json string I use `JsonObject` where I put all properties which I need then convert it to string using `toString()` method on `JsonObject` and send string as a message body. Everything works perfect unless I have a character in a string which is not from english alphabet. Example: µ. In this case instead of having correct json `{"Smth":"µ"}` in Datadog I'm getting incorrect string without closing curly brace `{"Smth":"µ"`. Has anybody experienced the same and knows how to deal with this?

Comment: Sounds like the second byte of a 2-byte Unicode overwrites your bracket.

Comment: Is there a way to fix?

Comment: Did you run a local test to see the result of `toString()`?  I'm not familiar with Datadog in general and its handling of extended character sets.

Comment: All cases without special characters work as expected